# Why does this keep recreating my database?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent nhibernate and have this line

```
 private static void BuidSchema(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config)
    {
        new SchemaExport(config).Execute(false,true,false);
    }
```

now this keeps on recreating my database. Am I misunderstanding the parameters?

[documentation](http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html#M:NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute%28System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean%29)

```
script
    true if the ddl should be outputted in the Console.
export
    true if the ddl should be executed against the Database.
justDrop
    true if only the ddl to drop the Database objects should be executed.
format
    true if the ddl should be nicely formatted instead of one statement per line.
```

I thought setting the justDrop to false would stop my db from being recreated if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set export to true it will drop a recreate your database.

Comment: ryudice then what does jsutDrop do? Is it possible to have it so that only creates your db if it does not exist?